# WiFi sometimes does not work after wake up from suspend

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, iwlwifi

We upgraded several computers from Linux Mint 17.3 to version 18 and later recently to 18.1. I say this, as the particular computer did not have this kind of problem before this release upgrade.

That was a big step for sure, as the Ubuntu base changed from 14.04 to 16.04.

Everything works under normal conditions, but we have one computer, that the user suspends to memory several times a day.

The problem is that sometimes, approximately 1 from 100 times, the WiFi does not work.

More precisely, when we wake that computer up from sleep, the WiFi seems to be on, but does not show up any wireless connections, the user can switch the WiFi off and on, in the panel, but that does not help.

When I, the *troubleshooter*, am at the computer and try like 10 times to suspend and wake it up, then it *of course* works.

---

Hardware:

- laptop Lenovo IdeaPad Z50
- card Wireless 3160

Kernel and driver:

- 4.4.0-59-generic
- iwlwifi

OS and DE:

- Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit
- Cinnamon

I am trying to read logs and find some clues as to what causes this and how to fix it, but to me it's like finding a needle in a haystack.

So I have defined the following alias for the user to try it out when this happens, which may be during the week or today, so I will report, if this helps or not:

```
alias wifi='sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We believe that in this case this issue was caused by kernel.

The reason being that since we upgraded it to 4.8, it does not happen.

Case solved for me.